# How to pass value of a label from one form to another form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, forms, label

I am new in Vb.net. I'm still studying the logics in this language. I want to output data in a label.text from form 1 to form 2 with the  use of a button. How can I do that while both forms are running?

PS. label.text may change value every time I click the button.

Comment: Which form opened the other? Which has the button and which one has the label?

Comment: i want to do it while both forms are open. Form 1 has the button and the value for the label. Form2 has the label. What i want to do is everytime i click the button form2 will output the value right away, Im quite confused on how can i do it cause im  still learning. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options.

- Use a property setter
- Use a method

**Note**: The code below assumes the following:

- Form1: Button (name: Button1)
- Form2: Label (name: Label1)

When the button is clicked on Form1, if Form2 isn't open, it opens it. Additionally, the value of the label on Form2 is set.

**Option 1:** (use a property setter)

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim f2 As Form2 = Nothing

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If f2 Is Nothing Then
            'create new instance
            f2 = New Form2

            'show form
            f2.Show()
        Else
            'show window
            'if window is minimized, it will "unminimize" it
            'f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal

            'bring window into focus
            'also brings the window to front
            'f2.Activate()
        End If

        'set value
        Dim username As String = String.Format("user{0}", counter)

        'set property value
        f2.Username = username

        counter += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2.vb**

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim _username As String = String.Empty

    Public Property Username As String
        Get
            Return _username
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _username = value
            Label1.Text = value
            Label1.Refresh()
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Option 2:** (use a method)

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim f2 As Form2 = Nothing

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If f2 Is Nothing Then
            'create new instance
            f2 = New Form2

            'show form
            f2.Show()
        Else
            'show window
            'if window is minimized, it will "unminimize" it
            'f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal

            'bring window into focus
            'also brings the window to front
            'f2.Activate()
        End If

        'set value
        Dim username As String = String.Format("user{0}", counter)

        'set value using method
        f2.SetLabelText(username)

        counter += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2.vb**

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Sub SetLabelText(ByVal username As String)
        Label1.Text = username
        Label1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Resources**:

- [How to: Create a Property (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-create-a-property)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it! Blessings!

Comment: It's OK to offer advice on how the acceptance/voting system works, but I'd suggest it is done in comments, not in answers. Moreover, I think it's probably best done sparingly, rather than as a matter of course - maybe where you suspect that the OP isn't familiar with the site. We want voting to be organic here, and not a duty.