# How to invoke a messagebox in a form from a class?

Tags: c#, winforms

*Help*, I'm not a veteran at this, but I'm trying to learn as much as I can. I need to do several things, all related:

1-Change the text of a button from a class that is not inside the form.
2-Invoke a messagebox.show from my class, passing the text to be displayed.
I would appreciate the understanding of anyone who can guide me. **I love you**.

I provided this:

```
Form1 form_Inv = new Form1();
form_Inv.label1.Text="exampletext";
form_Inv.button1.Text = "exampletext";
```

but it didn't work, it didn't throw an exception, it just didn't do anything.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110658/10024425 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425. The post are for VB.NET, but the same principles apply for C#.

Comment: You should call `Refresh();` on the Label & the Button after updating the text (To force an update of the display).
Also: consider doing the computation and processing in a background Task. In that case any changes in the UI should be done using `BeginInvoke`. See e.g. https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/winforms.html

Comment: A usefull link concerning the Messagebox: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/understanding-message-box-in-windows-forms-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [delegate/event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) to achieve both task.

Given the following class

```cs
internal class Operations
{
    public delegate void OnPassData(string text);
    public event OnPassData? PassData;

    public delegate void OnShow(string text);
    public event OnShow? Show;
    public void PassTextToCaller()
    {
        PassData?.Invoke("Greetings");
    }

    public void ShowMessageBox()
    {
        Show?.Invoke("Was called from a class");
    }
}
```

In the form, create an instance of the class above, [subscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#to-subscribe-to-events-programmatically) to the two events in the form constructor (or Shown event).

Below there are two buttons to call methods in the Operations class which in turn invoke the proper event.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Operations _operations = new Operations();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _operations.PassData += _operations_PassData;
        _operations.Show += _operations_Show;

    }

    private void ChangeTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _operations.PassTextToCaller();
    }
    private void _operations_PassData(string text)
    {
        ChangeTextButton.Text = text;
    }

    private void ShowMessageBoxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _operations.ShowMessageBox();
    }

    private void _operations_Show(string text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```